# Pairing the Arf with Stiefel-Whitney class

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, characteristic-classes, spin-geometry, cobordism

1. The [Arf invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arf_invariant) is a nonsingular quadratic form over a field of characteristic 2.

The form that I looked at was:
$$
S(q)=|H^1(M^2,\mathbb{Z}_2)|^{-1/2} \sum_{x\in H^1(M^2,\mathbb{Z}_2)} \exp[\pi \;i\; q(x)]
$$ 
see [Kirby-Taylor, Pin structures on low-dimensional manifolds](https://math.berkeley.edu/~kirby/papers/Kirby%20and%20Taylor%20-%20Pin%20structures%20on%20low-dimensional%20manifolds%20-%20MR1171915.pdf).

The $M^2$ is an oriented 2 dimensional manifold with spin structures that has $\mathbb{Z}_2$ valued quadratic forms on $H_1(M^2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$, which obeys $$q(x + y) = q(x) +
x ∩ y + q(y) \mod 2,$$ here $x ∩ y$ denotes the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ intersection pairing. The bordism invariant is the Arf invariant.

2. Stiefel-Whitney class is $\mathbb{Z}_2$-characteristic class associated to real vector bundles. For example, we can take the $w_i(TM)$ for the tangent bundle of the base manifold $M$.

> **Question**:
>
> - Is there some precise way to pair the Arf invariant $S(q)$ (or any **variation** of Arf) as a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-cohomology class $\text{arf}$ with Stiefel-Whitney class $w_i(TM)$? How would one write and define them formally as a topological invariant? Like
>     $$
>   \text{arf} \cup w_{d-2}(TM)?
>   $$
>     where the $M$ is a $d$-dimensional manifold? How do one cup product this two objects formally?
> - Must this $\text{arf} \cup w_{d-2}(TM)$ be a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-characteristic class?
> - What will be a nontrivial manifold generator $M$ for such an invariant $\text{arf} \cup w_{d-2}(TM)$?
> - How to view the Poincare dual PD for the 2 and $d-2$ submanifolds from $\text{arf}$ or $w_{d-2}(TM)$?

This is a variation of the problem from a previous Math.SE post which receives 0 feedback.

Comment: One problem with this is that the Arf invariant is either $1$ or $-1$, whereas Stiefel-Whitney classes are an element of mod 2 cohomology, in which $1$ and $-1$ are equal. So these things just look different to me.

Comment: sorry, let us map the Arf invariant  1 or −1 to 0 and 1 mod 2 cohomology. Is that possible?